# angular directive for tables: bind transcluded elements with ng-bind-html

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-controller, transclusion

I'm trying to write a generic table directive like this:

```
<h-table rows="customers">
  <h-column field="Id">
    <a ng-click="editCustomer(row.Id)">{{row.Id}}</a>
  </h-column>
  <h-column field="Name">
  </h-column>
</h-table>
```

That will generate the following html:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Id</th>
    <th>Name</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a ng-click="editCustomer(1)">1</a>
    </td>
    <td>
      Alexandre
    </td>
  </tr>
  ...
</table>
```

My h-table template is something like:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="hTableTemplate.html">
    <div>
        <div ng-transclude id="limbo" style="display: none"></div>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th ng-repeat="col in cols">{{col.field}}<th>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="row in rows">
                <td ng-repeat="col in cols">
                    // Here I need to put the content of h-column directive 
                    // if it exists, or just bind the value for the column
                    <span ng-bind-html="getContentOrValueFor(row, col)" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        <table>
    </div>
</script>
```

So I need to create two directives: h-table and h-column. The h-table directive uses a directive controller, that will be used by both directives. 
The h-column directive will use this controller to add cols to the table and get value of a row/col.

So far, this is my directive's controller:

```
.controller("hTable", function ($scope, $element, $attrs, $compile) {
    $scope.cols = [];

    this.addCol = function (col) {
        $scope.cols.push(col);
    };

    $scope.getContentOrValueFor = function (row, col) {
        // MY PROBLEM IS HERE! I will explain below ...
        return col.content && col.content.html() ? col.content.html() : row[col.field];
    };
})
```

My h-column directive receives h-table's controller. 
It uses transclude to get it content and save this content inside col object, to bind it after:

```
.directive("hColumn", function () {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        require: "^hTable",
        transclude: true,
        scope: {
            field: "@",
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, hTableController, transclude) {
            var col = {};
            col.field = scope.field;
            col.content = transclude();  // <-- Here I save h-column content to bind after
            hTableController.addCol(col);
            ...
        }
    };
})
```

And finally :) my h-table directive:

```
.directive("hTable", function () {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        scope : {
            rows: "="
        },
        controller: "hTable",
        require: "hTable",
        replace: true,
        transclude: true,
        templateUrl: "hTableTemplate.html",
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, hTableController) {
        ...
        }
    };
})
```

I need to put h-column's content inside the td tag. So, I call getContentOrValueFor function to get this content that was inside h-column's directive.

If there is no content, so I bind with the value for the field.

It works normally if the h-column's content is something like {{1+2+3}} (it will show me 6, that's ok).

But if this content is an html tag like:

```
<a href="somelink">test</a>
```

I get the error "html.indexOf is not a function"

How can I achieve this??

Answer (score 0):

Thats caused by not including ngSanatize i think. See : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml